# How to open an img from a slider in a new window

Tags: javascript

I have created an image slider with a very large set of images in img tags. I am trying to create code where when an image in the slider is clicked, it's opened in a new tab/window. Here's what I have so far:

```
var allSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide img');

for(i = 0; i < allSlides.length; i++){
    allSlides[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        window.open(allSlides[i].src);
    })
}
```

When I type allSlides[0] into the console, I get good output (e.g. `<img src="123">`, but when I click an image, I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined at HTMLImageElement.`<anonymous>`".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `window.open(event.target.src)`

Comment: window.open(this.src);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is because of the closure. When you `click` the image, `i` is going to be the length of `allSlides`, not the `i` you defined in the loop. Either you need to bind `i` to the click handler, or better yet, use the source of the clicked element like :

```
allSlides[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
  window.open(event.target.src);
});
```

You could also do it like:

```
allSlides.forEach(function(slide) {
  slide.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log(slide.src);
  });
});
```

creating a different scope per slide, removing the need for the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer! I used it, with a slightly different solution, getting this:

```
var allSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide img');

for(i = 0; i < allSlides.length; i++){
    allSlides[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        window.open(this.src);
    });
}
```

It works now! Thanks so much!